# Javascript animate line and image - library

Tags: javascript, animation

I have been researching a way to simultaneously animate a line and images.

see gif example here:

[image]

but I can not find any library to do this easily. I have attempted to use raw javascript but its too complicated and not working smooth. Do you have any libraries that can accomplish the animation shown in the gif? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably the first example of animating a line like this is from [Jake Archibald](https://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/), who used SVG with a dashed stroke length that varied over time. This could be the basis of your vertical line. With a bit of modification it could use the scroll position instead of time.

There is a library specifically for this line animation technique called [Vivus](https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/).

But if you're looking for a more full-featured SVG library that would give you a lot more options you could look at [SnapSVG](http://snapsvg.io), [Bonsai](https://bonsaijs.org) and [Velocity](http://velocityjs.org).